# Variables inside a string in Python

Tags: python, string

I am confused. I can not understand why something like in Python works fine:

```
 PPcode = 'something'
 createNode = {"statement":"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:"+PPcode+", id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', t: '1'})"}
```

and something like this gives me an error:

```
 createNode = {"statement":"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:"something", id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"}
```

The only difference is the nodeType property. Instead of having a variable I just pass the value directly. If in the second snippet I change the double quotes to single it works but if I do the same in the first snippet the PPcode variable is treated as a string. What the heck?? Some help please!

Comment: `createNode = {"statement":"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:14, id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"}` is the equivelent of the first statement ...

Comment: `"abc"14"de"` is in reality `"abc"  14   "de"`, that is, two strings separated by an integer. Invalid syntax, cause by a simple typographical error.

Comment: Its non necesserally an integer. I actually have a string in the PPcode variable.

Comment: `"abc"  something   "de"` would raise an error again. `something` is **not** a string, since 2nd quotation mark is closing the first string, and 3rd quotation mark is starting the second string, leaving `something` as an undefined name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the dictionary

```
{"statement":"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:"14", id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"}
```

the value is

```
"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:"14", id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"
```

Since the double quotes `"` determines the start/end of a string, the line mentioned before will be equivalent to:

```
string14string
```

which is not a valid sintax.

**What can you do to solve it?** Maybe you can concatenate the number `14`, but by using its string representation:

```
string + str(14) + string
```

which will lead to:

```
"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:" + str(14) + ", id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"
```

**Edit:**

- As per your clarification, it is important to note that string concatenation is done with the `+` operator:

  ```
  "CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:" + "some other string" + ", id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"
  ```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The number was just an example. Actually I have a string there. This is what I pass in the PPcode variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your working code evaluates to

```
"statement":"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:14, id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"
```

and your broken code evaluates to

```
"statement":"CREATE (bconf:DslBconf {nodeType:"14", id: 'DSL-MINI-BCONF-ALU', temaxia: '1'})"
```

One has quotes around the 14 and one doesn't

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, nodeType is passed in as an integer, in the second it is a string.

```
nodeType: 14
```

vs.

```
nodeType: "14"
```